# Hibernate delete silently failing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, hibernate-mapping

I am using Java+JPA+Hibernate+Playframework1 in a web application and have models Classroom, Student and Group (see below). Each model has exactly one instance in database, and those instances are related to each other. Ideally, deleting a classroom should also delete it's groups, and dissociate it's students, deleting a student should dissociate it's classrooms and groups, and deleting a group should dissociate it's students, but it is not working.

```
|Classroom|[Many]-------[Many]|Student|
   [One]                        [Many]
     |                           /
     |                          /
   [Many]                      /
   |Group|[Many]--------------´
```

When I try to delete a classroom, a student or a group they are simply not deleted. No runtime exception, no SQL error, no nothing. It just fails silently. I even activated sql debug and didn't see any delete, just selects.

**Update:** Somehow, courses with groups not related to students are deleted correctly.

Here are mappings:

```
@Entity(name = "r_classroom")
public class Classroom extends Model {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classroom", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "classrooms", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    public List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public String name;
}

@Entity(name = "r_student")
public class Student extends Model {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    public List<Classroom> classrooms = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    public List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    public String name;
}

@Entity(name = "r_group")
public class Group extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Classroom classroom;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    public List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public String name;
}
```

*The Model class is part of Play Framework. I am using Play 1.4.4.*

I believe something is wrong with my mappings, but what?

I posted the source code at [github](https://github.com/greenled/hibernate-delete-not-working).

Comment: I don't know PlayFramwork, but if you don't see any DELETE in the log you could be missing transactions or a flush, so hibernate never tries to delete on the database

Comment: This should not be the case, Play Framework handles transactions for you. Somehow, if the group is empty (no related Student) deletes work as expected.

Comment: What happens if you do a flush() after the delete?

Comment: `deleting a classroom should also delete its groups` - that's not going to happen on its own, as long as there are `Student`s belonging to that group. You will need to remove the association manually. The fact that `courses with groups not related to students are deleted correctly` is not really surprising, but in any other case, you should be getting a bunch of constraint violation exceptions.

Comment: @tom if I do a flush() after the delete() the result is still the same

Comment: @crizzis the `Classroom` entity has a `OneToMany` mapping to `Group`, so DELETEs on the first should be cascaded to the second, right? And I would be happier seeing at least constraint violation exceptions, but as said I get no errors, no exceptions.

Comment: The cascade from `Classroom` to `Group` is not the problem. The problem is that `Group` itself cannot be deleted, because there are `Student`s that still refer to that `Group`. As I said, these references will not be 'unset' automatically by JPA, you will need to dereference the `Group` to be deleted from each of its `Student`s manually.

Comment: @crizzis hummm I thought Hibernate would 'unset' the students for me. Will try with a method annotated with `@PreRemove` that clears `Group`s `Student`s list and see what happens.

Comment: What will happen is that it will most likely fail. You're not supposed to alter the relationship state within entity listeners, they're meant to allow you to modify *non-relationship* state only. The behavior of JPA after modifying the relationship state is not well defined, and Hibernate might handle it in a specific way, but it may just as well fail at commit time